# PLSQL Procedure taking lot of time to execute

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a Oracle PLSQL procedure which has a parent cursor and 2 child cursors (created in body) with reference to parent cursor value.

When I run the SQL statement direclt, it is returning the result immediately. However, when I put them in PLSQL procedure, it running endlessly.

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SENDTASKREMINDER
    AS
      l_html VARCHAR2(32767);
      r_html VARCHAR2(32767);
      l_exst NUMBER;
      ownerId NUMBER;
      CURSOR OwnerCursor IS SELECT DISTINCT TASK_OWNER_ID FROM TASKS 
          WHERE to_char(TASK_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') >= to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY') AND to_char(TASK_DUE_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') <= to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY')
      UNION
      SELECT DISTINCT TASK_OWNER_ID FROM TASKS 
          WHERE to_char(TASK_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') > to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY'); 
    BEGIN
      l_html := '<html>
        <head>
          <title>Task Reminder</title>
        </head>
        <body>';

      r_html := l_html;
      /* Get Pending Tasks */
      OPEN OwnerCursor;
      LOOP 
        FETCH OwnerCursor INTO ownerId;
        r_html := l_html;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_exst FROM TASKS 
            WHERE TASK_OWNER_ID = ownerId AND to_char(TASK_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') >= to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY') AND to_char(TASK_DUE_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') <= to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY');
        IF l_exst > 0
        THEN  
          r_html := r_html || '<h1>Your current pending tasks</h1><table><tr><th>Task Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Due Date</th></tr>';   
          FOR PendingCursor IN (SELECT PK_TASK_ID, TASK_NAME, TASK_DESCRIPTION, TASK_START_DATE, TASK_DUE_DATE FROM TASKS 
              WHERE TASK_OWNER_ID = ownerId AND to_char(TASK_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') >= to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY') AND to_char(TASK_DUE_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') <= to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY'))
          LOOP
            r_html := r_html || '<tr><td>' || PendingCursor.TASK_NAME || '</td><td>' || PendingCursor.TASK_DESCRIPTION || '</td><td>' || PendingCursor.TASK_DUE_DATE ||'</td></tr>';
          END LOOP;
          r_html := r_html || '</table>';
        END IF;

        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_exst FROM  TASKS 
           WHERE TASK_OWNER_ID = ownerId AND to_char(TASK_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') > to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY')  ;  
        IF l_exst > 0
        THEN  
          r_html := r_html || '<h1>Your future tasks</h1><table><tr><th>Task Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Due Date</th></tr>';   
          FOR FutureCursor IN (SELECT PK_TASK_ID, TASK_NAME, TASK_DESCRIPTION, TASK_START_DATE, TASK_DUE_DATE   FROM  TASKS 
              WHERE TASK_OWNER_ID = ownerId AND to_char(TASK_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') > to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY')  )
          LOOP
            r_html := r_html || '<tr><td>' || FutureCursor.TASK_NAME || '</td><td>' || FutureCursor.TASK_DESCRIPTION || '</td><td>' || FutureCursor.TASK_DUE_DATE ||'</td></tr>';
          END LOOP;
          r_html := r_html || '</table>';
        END IF;

r_html := r_html || '</body></html>';
        send_mail(p_to        => 'XXX.XXX@xxx.com',
                  p_from      => 'fromemail@xxx.com',
                  p_subject   => 'Your Pending and Future tasks for OwnerId' || ownerId,
                  p_text_msg  => 'text msg is not yet created',
                  p_html_msg  => r_html,
                  p_smtp_host => 'localhost');
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE OwnerCursor;
    END;
    /
```

Is there any unending loop created here. There is no error in PLSQL. I have edited this file before pasting here. So, if compilation error is found, then it is due to my edits. The actual procedure does not have any compilation error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `EXIT` after the fetch:

```
FETCH Ownercursor into ownerId;
EXIT WHEN Ownercursor%NOTFOUND;
```

Comment: If you're having a hard time understanding simple loops and exits, you might consider a for-loop as well. They are a bit easier to understand for beginners.

Comment: I have another problem now. It is sending about 1000+ emails with the same content. I have only 2 task_owners in my table for whom reminder emails would be sent. So, there should be just 2 emails sent to me (testing with my id). However, I am receiving 1000+ duplicate emails. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I do not seen any unending loop. Did you test the call to send_mail in a stand-alone procedure? It might be hanging up there.

You have another logic flaw in your where clause. You are using the TO_CHAR function wrong. This:

`AND to_char(TASK_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') >= to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY') AND to_char(TASK_DUE_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') <= to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY'))`

is not logically equivalent to this:

`TASK_START_DATE >= SYSDATE AND TASK_DUE_DATE <= SYSDATE))`

For example, if TASK_START_DATE is 01-APR-15 and TASK_DUE_DATE is 30-MAY-15 and today is 01-JUN-15, then your expression will evaluate to TRUE because "JUN" is alphabetically between "APR" and "MAY".

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Where to start. Diederikh and Scott covered a couple of glaring problems, but looking closer at the code, there is a lot that doesn't make sense.

First, is a "Current" task one with a start date in the past or present and due date in the future or present? Is a "Future" task one with a start date in the future? If so, you have the comparisons all wrong. According to your logic, a "Current" task is one with the start date in the future or present and the due date in the past or present.

Second, there are five(!) places where there are queries to go out and hit the database. There is no reason everything you need can't be read in with the initial cursor. Then just analyze and process as needed.

There are many other places I would make suggestions. I don't want to list all of them so I'll just include the code. You can take my minor suggestions or not, but be sure to verify your date logic and don't hit the database any more often than you absolutely have to. Thousands of lines of code can execute in the time it can take to perform one disk access. It's still not as polished as I'd like production code to be, but it's enough to get you started. And, although I don't have access to your table, it should work.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SENDTASKREMINDER AS
      l_html        VARCHAR2(100);
      r_html        VARCHAR2(32767);
      C_header      varchar2( 40 ) := '<h1>Your current pending tasks</h1>';
      F_header      varchar2( 32 ) := '<h1>Your future tasks</h1>';
      EndHeader     varchar2( 80 ) := '<table><tr><th>Task Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Due Date</th></tr>';
      EndFooter     varchar2( 32 ) := '</table></body></html>';
      PrevOwnerId   int         := -1; -- Must not be a valid OwnerID
      C_count       int         := 0;
      F_count       int         := 0;
      l_today       date        := Trunc( SysDate );
      CURSOR OwnerCursor IS 
        SELECT TASK_OWNER_ID, PK_TASK_ID, TASK_NAME, TASK_DESCRIPTION, TASK_START_DATE, TASK_DUE_DATE
        FROM TASKS
        WHERE (TASK_START_DATE <= l_today and TASK_DUE_DATE >= l_today)
            or TASK_START_DATE  > l_today
        order by TASK_OWNER_ID, TASK_START_DATE; -- So first the Current then Future tasks
BEGIN
    l_html := '<html><head><title>Task Reminder</title></head><body>';

    /* Get all Tasks */
    for OwnerRec in OwnerCursor LOOP
        if OwnerRec.TASK_OWNER_ID != PrevOwnerId then
            -- This is the first record for this owner. Unless it's also the first record of the loop,
            -- close the html and send the email.
            if C_count > 0 or F_count > 0 then
              r_html := r_html || EndFooter;
            end if;

            send_mail(p_to => 'XXX.XXX@xxx.com',
              p_from       => 'fromemail@xxx.com',
              p_subject    => 'Your Pending and Future tasks for OwnerId' || ownerId,
              p_text_msg   => 'text msg is not yet created',
              p_html_msg   => r_html,
              p_smtp_host  => 'localhost');

            r_html      := l_html;
            PrevOwnerId := OwnerRec.TASK_OWNER_ID;
            C_count     := 0;
            F_count     := 0;
        end if;

        if OwnerRec.TASK_START_DATE <= l_today then
            if C_count = 0 then
                -- This is the first Current entry, write the header
                r_html := r_html || C_header || EndHeader;
            end if;
            C_count := c_count + 1;
        else
            if F_count = 0 then
                -- This is the first Future entry. See if there were any Current entries
                if C_count > 0 then
                    -- There was, so terminate the Current table
                    r_html := r_html || '</table>';
                    C_count := 0;
                end if;
                -- Write the header
                r_html := r_html || F_header || EndHeader;
            end if;
            F_count := F_count + 1;
        end if;

        -- Whether Current or Future, write the task particulars
        r_html  := r_html || '<tr><td>' || OwnerRec.TASK_NAME || '</td><td>' || OwnerRec.TASK_DESCRIPTION || '</td><td>' || OwnerRec.TASK_DUE_DATE ||'</td></tr>';
    END LOOP;

    -- The last owner has not completed processing. But maybe there were no tasks at all...
    if C_count > 0 or F_count > 0 then
        r_html := r_html || EndFooter;

        send_mail(p_to => 'XXX.XXX@xxx.com',
          p_from       => 'fromemail@xxx.com',
          p_subject    => 'Your Pending and Future tasks for OwnerId' || ownerId,
          p_text_msg   => 'text msg is not yet created',
          p_html_msg   => r_html,
          p_smtp_host  => 'localhost');

        dbms_output.put_line( r_html );
    end if;
END;
```